# secure static content with Jersey's RolesAllowedDynamicFeature

Tags: java, jersey

I'd like to serve static content using Jersey. The idea is to provide a login page followed by a web application on a successful login.
How do I secure the web application against unrestricted access using Jersey's RolesAllowedDynamicFeature?

Comment: Logging in is for _authentication_. `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` is for _authorization_, which are different animals. Which one do you need help with? Do you already have authentication handled? If so, how are you doing it. Are you looking for a full security solution? If that's the case, this question is too broad. Please narrow down your question to a specific problem you are having.

Comment: I want to avoid the case where a user directly requests the webapp. There should be a redirect to the login page if he's not logged in.